# Error in Power Automate, When a item is created or modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, error, power-automate, flow

I have a flow that is executed when a SharePoint item is modified. The list it refers to has a hidden lookup column, but when the flow step is executed, it fails in the trigger, it says:

> The query to the field 'CBForm' is not valid, The `$Select` query string must specify the target fields and the expand query string must contain CBForm.

But the action does not allow adding queries, and the list has not been changed either, how can I deal with this problem?

The fault is in trigger (step 1) of the flow, so I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in SharePoint. Lookup columns should not be hidden in the list view; if the column is hidden, Power Automate fails to retrieve the values, causing an error when starting the flow.

If the lookup column is hidden from its creation, it can be added to the view with PowerShell.